# Many django projects on same localhost & session management

Tags: django

As I am running four Django projects as subdomains of the same apache2 localhost, user sessions get confused and keep signing out.
I am using the standard Django authentication system.
Is there a solution for this problem?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that cookies are stored for a domain so all of your projects store the `sessionid` cookie (that's the default name for sessions) for the same domain; namely `localhost`. What ends up happening is each project overriding the `sessionid` cookie of the project you previously logged into thus "invalidating" the session. A simple solution would be using different cookie names for each project.

This can be done by explicitly setting the [`SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name) in your django settings to some value unique across all your projects e.g. the project name.

Comment: It appears to work fine with the SESSION_COOKIE_NAME. Thanks!